# Prevent enzyme shallow rendering on private component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

How do I prevent shallow rendering on private component with enzyme?

Here is a component example:

```
// foo.jsx 
import React from 'react';

// Private component
const FooSubtitle = ({subtitle}) => {
  if (!subtitle) return null;

  return <div className="foo__subtitle">{subtitle}</div>;
};

// Public component
const Foo = ({title, subtitle}) => (
  <div className="foo">
    <div className="foo__title">{title}</div>
    <FooSubtitle subtitle={subtitle} />
  </div>
);

export default Foo;
```

Here is my specification:

```
// foo.spec.js
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Foo from './foo.jsx';

describe('Foo', () => {

  it('should render a subtitle', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo title="my title" subtitle="my subtitle" />);

    // This test doesn't work, so I cannot test the render of my component
    expect(wrapper.find('.foo__subtitle').length).toBe(1);

    // This one works, but it is not relevant
    expect(wrapper.find('FooSubtitle').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `'.foo_subtitle'` should be `'.foo__subtitle'`, shouldn't it?

Comment: what do u mean by a private component

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yes, it should! thanks :) But it doesn't solve my problem :P

Comment: @Sagi_Avinash_Varma A private component is like the `FooSubtitle` component of my example. It is a component, declared to simplify the implementation, but it is not exposed. Am I clear?

Comment: @tzi can't you use [full DOM rendering](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) then in this case (or perhaps the [static rendering API](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/render.md))? Is that impractical in some way?

Comment: @Aurora0001 No, I don't want to use the `render()` API, because it will render the external component include in my component. Here it is a simplify example. But the `dive()` API is great, see my answer bellow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have private components, and you want to test their implementation, you should:

1. Have at least enzyme v2.5
2. Look at the [Enzyme .dive() API](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.md): Shallow render a non-DOM child of the current wrapper

Here is a working example:

```
// foo.jsx
import React from 'react';

// Private component
const FooSubtitle = ({subtitle}) => {
  if (!subtitle) return null;

  return <div className="foo__subtitle">{subtitle}</div>;
};

// Public component
const Foo = ({title, subtitle}) => (
  <div className="foo">
    <div className="foo__title">{title}</div>
    <FooSubtitle subtitle={subtitle} />
  </div>
);

export default Foo;
```

---

```
// foo.spec.js
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Foo from './foo.jsx';

describe('Foo', () => {

  it('should render a subtitle', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo title="my title" subtitle="my subtitle" />);

    // This test works, but it is not relevant
    expect(wrapper.find('FooSubtitle').length).toBe(1);

    // This one need the `dive()` API to work
    expect(wrapper.find('FooSubtitle').dive().find('.foo__subtitle').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a
>   component as a unit, **and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly
>   asserting on behavior of child components**.

I think you are trying to do what shallow tries to avoid ^^.

You can unit test the private component directly or use render :

```
expect(wrapper.find(Foo).render().find('.foo__subtitle')).to.have.length(1);
```

as explaned here : https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/render.md

But in both cases you'll need to export your Component and I must admit I had an error testing it with your component. :/

Answer (score 1):

In this case (and in generally) your private component is just a function, use it as a function in the render of your public component and you will be able to test its render with the shallow wrapper.

```
<div className="foo">
  <div className="foo__title">{title}</div>
  {FooSubtitle({subtitle})}
</div>
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure it's a good idea to have complex private components...

Answer (score 1):

You have to export your private component,

```
export const FooSubtitle = ...
```

Now, you are able to test it apart with all its prop variants.

Then you can test the presence of FooSubtitle, with particular props, in the render of Foo component as usual and nothing more.